# imageareaselect with .live ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, crop

I'm making an ajax image upload and cropper using imageareaselect. The file gets uploaded and echo's into the page, which in turn should trigger the imgareaselect function.
The function works when i write this directly in to the document :

```
<div id="PhotoPrev"><img src="/uploads/image.jpeg ?>" alt="Photo Preview" id="photo" name="photo" /></div>
```

but when the image gets loaded through ajax it does'nt.
So i'm thinking i need a .live function for it, but struggling with how to.

this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
        aspectRatio: '1:1',
        onSelectEnd: getSizes
    });

$('#endre').click(function(){
$('.cropform').fadeIn();
$('#photoimg').fadeIn();
$("#endre").fadeOut();
});
});
$('#photoimg').live('change', function() { 
$("#thumbs").html('');
showLoader();               
$("#cropimage").ajaxForm({
target: '#thumbs'
}).submit();hideLoader();
});
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated on how to trigger areaselect after ajax uploads and echoes the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting everything inside `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
        aspectRatio: '1:1',
        onSelectEnd: getSizes
    });

    $('#endre').click(function() {
        $('.cropform').fadeIn();
        $('#photoimg').fadeIn();
        $("#endre").fadeOut();
    });

    $('#photoimg').live('change', function() {
        $("#thumbs").html('');
        showLoader();
        $("#cropimage").ajaxForm({
            target: '#thumbs'
        }).submit();
        hideLoader();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Havihavi ok, can you show me the function where you add the `img` through ajax?You must call `imgAreaSelect()` on them from there i think

Comment: Yep, you are right! i echoed the script from the ajax being called and it works now! thanks for the help Nicola :)

Answer (score 0):

Use .delegate() instead of .live(). I've been saying this a lot, but .live() turns out to be really anoying within a big DOM tree. That's because every time and event occurs on some element, this is launched up to the document element and handled there.

By using .delegate(), you can specify wich of the upper elements in the DOM you'd like to handle the event.

In this situation, you can do this:

```
$(SelectorToUpperElementInDOM).delegate('#photoimg',"change",function() { 
$("#thumbs").html('');
showLoader();               
$("#cropimage").ajaxForm({
target: '#thumbs'
}).submit();hideLoader();
})
```

Anyway, I can't be sure of what your callback functions does. Please specify if you need some more help.

Comment: ahh, this will come in handy!! thanks alot :)
I'm struggling with further handling of the cropped image, but i have to narrow down the error before i post any code. 

Thanks for answering =)